# Can reduceByKey function change the key?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to spark and probably I don't have a good understanding of reduce by key. I want to keep the cluster Id that is nearest to a point.

distancePointMicrocluster: `RDD[Point,(ClusterId: Int, Distance: Double)]`

```
    val nearestClusterToPoint = distancesPointMicrocluster.reduceByKey((x,y) => if (x._2 < y._2) x else y )
```

Input and Output of the function
[image]

Comment: Could you provide the exact and complete code that caused the problem, some sample data and the output you get? From what I see, your code seems correct. If you could tell us the version of spark you are using, it may help as well.

Comment: Look at the type of your RDD. It's [Int, Int]. Is this what you want to do? Maybe it could be the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem wasn't the function `reduceByKey` but the fact that I didn't save the points in memory. As a result I was recreating the points in every action and for that reason the `pointIds` weren't the same.